# how to slide element using bootstrap 3 grid system

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to implement sliding menu. I'm using bootstrap 3 grid system. How can I move element from one side to another using bootstrap's grid system?
Without grid system I would simply position my element absolutely and then change the `left` property like shown in [this Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/cnqcdyWKxYIofKxPzsiF?p=preview) but I feel that this solution would be incorrect. Any help?

HTML:

```
<button id="clickMe">Click me</button>
<div>Hello Plunker!</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  right:auto;
  transition: all 0.5s linear;
}


div.left {
  left:0;
}

div.left {
  left:200px;
}
```

JS:

```
  var el = document.getElementById('clickMe')
  el.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    var element = document.querySelector('div');
    if (element.classList.contains('left') {
      element.classList.remove('left');
      element.classList.add('right');
    } else {
      element.classList.remove('right');
      element.classList.add('left');
    }
  })
```

Comment: There is no sliding menu in Bootstrap's default. Look at http://jasny.github.io/bootstrap/javascript/#offcanvas for some ideas or inside the OffCanvas stuff in the core Bootstrap. http://getbootstrap.com/examples/offcanvas/. Generally you just toggle a class and use CSS transition to change the position when it's active or inactive.

Comment: Thanks! I'll take a look at links you provided